# Can't get Auth Code from Auth0 or Okta in Angular app using angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular, openid-connect, auth0, okta, angular-oauth2-oidc

I see an /authorize? call but no /code? message is ever received from auth0 or OKTA.

OK, let me start at the beginning.

Our typical login flow:

1. The user access our site at localhost:4200/ (just an example URL for this post)
2. an auth-guard is called, notes the user is not logged in, and reroutes to /login
3. on our login page, the user selects an organization code they need before we can log them in
4. The user selects 'next'
5. The user is presented with a login page by Auth0 and enters their credentials
6. Auth0 receives the message and calls the redirect URL, which is /callback

At this point I expect auth0 to return an auth code, then the library to request the access token, BUT NOTHING HAPPENS.

All the online examples seem to take the user from step 1 directly to step 5

We want to switch our angular app to use a generic library like angular-oauth2-oidc, but I should note that the flow works when we use auth0's angular library.

Currently, our callback page just presents the user with a spinner - it doesn't execute any code.  I suspect this might be the issue, but not sure, and not sure what it needs to do.

I also have not turned on silent refresh yet.

auth config (including defaults):

```
checkOrigin:false
clearHashAfterLogin:true
clientId:"<private>"
customQueryParams
: {identityProviders: '[{"connectionId":"google-oauth2","name":"Google Account"}]'}
customTokenParameters:[]
decreaseExpirationBySec:0
disableAtHashCheck:false
disableIdTokenTimer:false
disablePKCE:false
dummyClientSecret:""
issuer:"https://<private>.us.auth0.com/"
jwks:null
loginUrl:""
logoutUrl:""
nonceStateSeparator:";"
oidc:true
openUri:uri => { location.href = uri; }
options:null
postLogoutRedirectUri:""
preserveRequestedRoute:false
redirectUri:"http://localhost:4200/callback"
redirectUriAsPostLogoutRedirectUriFallback:true
requestAccessToken:true
requireHttps:"remoteOnly"
resource:""
responseType:"code"
revocationEndpoint:null
rngUrl:""
scope:"openid email profile"
sessionCheckIFrameName:"angular-oauth-oidc-check-session-iframe"
sessionCheckIFrameUrl:null
sessionCheckIntervall:3000
sessionChecksEnabled:false
showDebugInformation:true
silentRefreshIFrameName:"angular-oauth-oidc-silent-refresh-iframe"
silentRefreshMessagePrefix:""
silentRefreshRedirectUri:""
silentRefreshShowIFrame:false
silentRefreshTimeout:20000
siletRefreshTimeout:20000
skipIssuerCheck:false
skipSubjectCheck:false
strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation:false
timeoutFactor:0.75
tokenEndpoint:null
useHttpBasicAuth:false
useIdTokenHintForSilentRefresh:false
userinfoEndpoint:null
waitForTokenInMsec:0
```

auth guard:

```
  canActivate(next, state) {
    if (
      this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken() &&
      this.oauthService.hasValidIdToken()
    ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }  }
```

and my login code:

```
  loginWithRedirect(state?: any): Promise<boolean> {
    const oauthConfig: AuthConfig = this.getAuthConfig(state);

    this.oauthService.configure(oauthConfig);
    return this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin();
  }
```

Comment: Correction - I AM getting the auth code in the callback URL.  Nothing seems to be processing it automatically.

If I inject the service into the callback component, then call this.oauthService.tryLoginCodeFlow() from the constructor, the auth code is parsed correctly, but the token endpoint, populated by the previous call to document discovery, is missing, as if I am not getting the same instance of the oauth service that made the authorize endpoint call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin, we can use the initImplicitFlow method provided by the oauthService to redirect the user to Auth0 for authentication.

so please try the following

```
loginWithRedirect(state?: any): Promise<boolean> {
  const oauthConfig: AuthConfig = this.getAuthConfig(state);

  this.oauthService.configure(oauthConfig);
  return this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
}
```

here by using initImplicitFlow, the code should redirect the user to Auth0 for authentication and handle the retrieval of the access token automatically.

try this and let us know.

Comment: isn't implicitFlow frowned upon?

When I tried the above, I never get the login page from auth0

Comment: instead of from constructer can you try it from ngOnInit `export class CallbackComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.oauthService.tryLoginCodeFlow();
  }

}` try this and tell me

Comment: That works.  I had to reload the discover doc - apparently when the callback endpoint is called the whole page refreshes (app restart) and all previous context is lost.  Is this expected?  (Our old login flow did the same - I just never noticed that before)

Comment: no, it should not but if it is happened that is indicating that there is some fault or issue in the implementation of the callback endpoint or in  the way it is being called/used in the application. if it all going smooth now then ok but if this behavior keeps occurring then we must look into it .

Comment: This is on me - the old aoth0 lib did the same thing (before my time).  Thanks for the help